# Remove duplicate lines from a variable

Tags: tcl

I am having a variable as stated below

```
 echo $test_output_assign_list
assign BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM = mbist_out.BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM;
assign BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM = mbist_out.BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM;
assign BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM = mbist_out.BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM;
assign BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM = mbist_out.BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM;
assign BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM = mbist_out.BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM;
assign BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM = mbist_out.BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM;
assign BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM = mbist_out.BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM;
assign BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM = mbist_out.BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM;
```

I want to remove the duplicate lines from this variable

The variable should be

```
assign BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM = mbist_out.BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM;
```

I have written small script as stated below but it is not giving right result

```
foreach k $test_output_assign_list {
set un [lsort -unique $k] 
}

echo $un 

{mbist_out.BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM;}
```

I am not getting the right result here

Answer (score 0):

```
% set test_output_assign_list {assign BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM = mbist_out.BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM;
assign BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM = mbist_out.BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM;
assign BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM = mbist_out.BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM;
assign BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM = mbist_out.BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM;
assign BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM = mbist_out.BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM;
assign BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM = mbist_out.BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM;
assign BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM = mbist_out.BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM;
assign BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM = mbist_out.BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM;}
assign BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM = mbist_out.BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM;
assign BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM = mbist_out.BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM;
assign BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM = mbist_out.BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM;
assign BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM = mbist_out.BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM;
assign BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM = mbist_out.BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM;
assign BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM = mbist_out.BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM;
assign BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM = mbist_out.BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM;
assign BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM = mbist_out.BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM;

% set test [split $lines \n]
{assign BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM = mbist_out.BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM;} {assign BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM = mbist_out.BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM;} {assign BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM = mbist_out.BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM;} {assign BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM = mbist_out.BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM;} {assign BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM = mbist_out.BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM;} {assign BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM = mbist_out.BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM;} {assign BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM = mbist_out.BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM;} {assign BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM = mbist_out.BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM;}

% set uniques [lsort -unique $lines]
{assign BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM = mbist_out.BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM;}

% set unique [lindex $unique 0]
assign BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM = mbist_out.BIST_DATA_FROM_MEM;
```

Comment: This is also working                                                                                              
 set a  [concat  [lindex $test_output_assign_list 0] [lindex $test_output_assign_list 1] [lindex $test_output_assign_list 2] [lindex $test_output_assign_list 3]]

Answer (score 0):

You should *first split the input into lines,* then remove the duplicates. There are a few ways to the duplicate removal, depending exactly what you mean by it and what sort of ordering you are interested in. Here's one way, using a dictionary to do the duplicate removal, which uses the order of first occurrence of each unique line:

```
set deduplicated {}
foreach line [split $test_output_assign_list "\n"] {
    dict set deduplicated $line 1
}
set deduplicated [join [dict keys $deduplicated] "\n"]
```

Comment: I've converted the result back into a (potentially) multi-line string.